# What is the name for the opening in the mouth for the nasal passages?

Tags: human-anatomy, terminology, anatomy

Is there a proper anatomical name for the opening in the soft palette where the nasal passages enter the mouth?

Comment: Something other than oropharynx?

Comment: @skymningen From looking at drawings it looks like I'm talking about where the nasopharynx meets the oropharynx. There may not be a specific name for it. Sometimes openings have their own separate name (like the foramen magnum, or the anus, etc) but not always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand from your comment is that you are asking for opening which connects the nasopharynx to oropharynx.

This opening is is connecting two parts of pharynx , acting like a bridge therefore it was named as **Pharyngeal/Nasopharyngeal isthmus.**

According to [this site:](http://www.medilexicon.com/dictionary/46048)

> isthmus of pharynx
>
> Type:Term
>
> Definitions
>   1. passage posterior to the soft palate by which the nasopharynx and oropharynx communicate (i.e., the junction of nasopharynx and oropharynx), closed during swallowing by elevation of the soft palate and contraction of the posterior fascicle of palatopharyngeus (muscle), forming a Passavant cushion.
>
> Synonyms 
>   isthmus pharyngis , pharyngeal isthmus

[image]

---

Source of image: [Textbook of Anatomy: Head, Neck, and Brain : Vishram Singh](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=bNTgAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA200&lpg=PA200&dq=vishram%20singh%20pathways%20of%20food&source=bl&ots=g_vnsgpB8D&sig=S8AiqVXpnpEdloes92Tk5lvWlsQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMkrmJyeXTAhWLto8KHekNAMgQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=vishram%20singh%20pathways%20of%20food&f=false)